Multiselect dropdown overlaps my table, I want the dropdown to push the table down
I'm encountering an issue where a multiselect dropdown is overlapping a table in my web application. Despite trying various CSS adjustments and manipulating the z-index, the problem persists.
My css file:
.content-container {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}


.multiselect-component .multiselect-dropdown {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.scrollable-table {
    max-height: 600px; /* Adjust based on your requirement */
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: visible;
}

thead.thead-dark {
    background-color: #343a40;
    color: #ffffff;
}

th,
td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Button Styles */
button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

Part of my js file:
<div className="scrollable-table">
            <div className="content-container">
                <div className="dropdown-container">
                    <Multiselect
                        options={events}
                        selectedValues={selectedEventsForMultiselect}
                        onSelect={onSelectedEventsChange}
                        onRemove={onSelectedEventsChange}
                        displayValue="name"
                        showCheckbox={true}
                        onFocus={toggleDropdown}
                        onBlur={toggleDropdown}
                        className="multiselect-component"
                    />
                </div>
                <div style={{ marginTop: isDropdownActive ? "200px" : "20px" }}>
                    <button onClick={handleDisplayStudentsClick}>Display Students</button>

                    <h2>Total Students: {students.length}</h2>

                    <table className="table-text-small">
                        <thead className="thead-dark">

I tried changing z-index values and margins. Nothing works. Any help is greatly appreciated

"Part of my js file:" no it's not js at all (nor is is JavaScript)

According to what you've given, it seems that you are using an external library, and to add the additional custom styles to it, you will have to add !important to the CSS properties in your CSS file.
See this example:
.multiselect-component {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}

